# Action Naming Convention

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Has anybody established a good naming convention for action in MVC?  I was specifically looking at ASP.net MVC but it is a general question.  For instance I have an action which displays the login screen (Login) and one which process the login request from that page (LoginTest).  I'm not keen on the names and I have a lot of the applicaiton left to write.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Rob Conery at MS suggested some useful RESTful style naming for actions.

> ```
> * Index - the main "landing" page. This is also the default endpoint.
> * List - a list of whatever "thing" you're showing them - like a list of Products.
> * Show - a particular item of whatever "thing" you're showing them (like a Product)
> * Edit - an edit page for the "thing"
> * New - a create page for the "thing"
> * Create - creates a new "thing" (and saves it if you're using a DB)
> * Update - updates the "thing"
> * Delete - deletes the "thing"
> ```

results in URLs along the lines of (for a forum)

> ```
> * http://mysite/forum/group/list - shows all the groups in my forum
> * http://mysite/forum/forums/show/1 - shows all the topics in forum id=1
> * http://mysite/forums/topic/show/20 - shows all the posts for topic id=20
> ```

[Rob Conery on RESTful Architecture for MVC](http://blog.wekeroad.com/2007/12/06/aspnet-mvc-using-restful-architecture/)

Comment: I also see that with the newest MVC you can set which verbs are accepted by an action so you can name an action Edit for both the initial page load and the saving the information.

Comment: Seems that post from Rob Conery predates the ability to gave both the display form and process form methods named the same. I also note the Nerd Dinner sample has Edit, but the Controller template has Update for modifying an entity.

Comment: I like this - only problem is you end up with multiple view files in the project with the same name (e.g. 'Edit'), making it confusing when working with lots of files open in VS. Anybody know a neat solution? I'm currently calling the views "EditProduct", "ViewProduct" etc.

Comment: Link's dead - there's a snapshot on Archive.org - http://web.archive.org/web/20130119131317/http://wekeroad.com/2007/12/06/aspnet-mvc-using-restful-architecture

Answer (score 4):

Rails has a nice action naming convention for CRUD operations: [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions).

`HTTP Verb   Path                Controller#Action   Used for
GET         /photos             photos#index        display a list of all photos
GET         /photos/new         photos#new          return an HTML form for creating a new photo
POST        /photos             photos#create       create a new photo
GET         /photos/:id         photos#show         display a specific photo
GET         /photos/:id/edit    photos#edit         return an HTML form for editing a photo
PATCH/PUT   /photos/:id         photos#update       update a specific photo
DELETE      /photos/:id         photos#destroy      delete a specific photo`

*This is essentially an update to [Paul Shannon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/120227/1171227),
since his source (Rob Conery) implicitly says that he copied his list from Rails.*

Answer (score 1):

I've found a [blog post by Stephen Walther](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/06/27/asp-net-mvc-tip-11-use-standard-controller-action-names.aspx) useful for finding a consistent naming scheme. His are also derived from a REST-style naming scheme, with some unique exceptions that he explains.

Comment: Link doesn't seem to work any longer, it goes to a list of MVC articles but none seem relevant to this discussion. Anyone have an updated link?

Comment: Here's the updated link: http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/06/27/asp-net-mvc-tip-11-use-standard-controller-action-names.aspx

Comment: The link is not broken

Answer (score 1):

Stephen Walther's post on [ASP.NET MVC Tip #11 – Use Standard Controller Action Names](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/06/27/asp-net-mvc-tip-11-use-standard-controller-action-names) would probably clarify you regarding to naming convention of `MVC Action` naming convention...

Answer (score 0):

The builtin Django actions suffix _done.  So LoginDone would be the page that processes Login (in ASP.NET MVC camel case style).

Comment: That is okay, but it implies that logging in has been completed when really the done action is processing the login.  Perhaps PromptLogin and Login.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly irrelevant which convention you use for the Controller Action naming, as long as it's consistant for you and easily understood by those working on it.

In the case of your login Actions, LoginDone is fine and in the same was ProcessLogin will is easy to understand, so use a convention that you feel comfortable with.

Personally I would probably side with Login and ProcessLogin, as LoginDone is probably slightly misleading in terms of what the Action is doing - this is of course assuming that the Action is reacting to the users' credentials and checking whether they are valid. You could then pass through to another Action called LoginDone once the login is successful, or LoginFailed if it's not.