# MVC naming conventions for JSON actions

Tags: json, model-view-controller, naming-conventions

What naming convention is recommended when writing an MVC app that has both front-end and JSON paths to the required data?

For example, let's say the user of your site has "Things".  They should be able to go to a page to view their things, but we also need a way to pull those things back as JSON on other pages.  I've been able to think of several options but I'm not keen enough on any of them to proceed.  Here's what I've got:

1. **/things/list** for UI, **/json/things** for JSON - this would require a JsonController which would end up serving different kinds of objects, thereby defeating any chance of entity separation before we even start.
2. **/things/list** for UI, **/things/list/json** for JSON - probably my preferred option at the moment, but requires magic stringing (albeit just "json").  Also, if you also need a (string id) action signature for taking in some filter parameters or such, then you have the choice of adding an extra route or doing some dirty string splitting.
3. **/account/mythings** for UI, **/things/list** for JSON - a bit cleaner, but there might not always be a relevant controller that you could serve the "things" from.  Plus, you're mixing entities again.

All and any suggestions welcome, thanks!

Comment: Please have a look at my answer on  [Action Naming Convention](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118474/action-naming-convention/38994001#38994001). Hope this helps...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Arguably the path names could all be the same.  You can examine the Accept header for the mime-type of your client's desired response, and then return an appropriate view based on what you find there:

- application/json: JSON View
- text/xml: XML View
- text/plain, text/html: JSP
  View

Browsers set this field to HTML; your JSON clients would simply set this field as appropriate.

Comment: I agree.  This is what HTTP content negotiation is designed for.

I would recommend defining your own mime types so that you can version your JSON data formats.  Something like application/vnd.mycorp.myformat-1.0+json.  That way, when something changes in your format, you can change it to application/vnd.mycorp.myformat-1.1+json (for a backward compatible change) or application/vnd.mycorp.myformat-2.0+json (for a backward incompatible change).

Comment: Brilliantly elegant, thanks!  The $.postJSON jQuery function I am using in my UI already sends the right headers, so this is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

It's highly unlikely that anyone would be bookmarking a URL that requests JSON so I think that it's not that important to keep the URL as clean. It's also likely to be programmatically generated, not hand entered. Given these, I'd consider adding it as a query parameter.

```
 /things/list  -- HTML
 /things/list?format=json  -- JSON
```

This won't break your URLs if you do have ID parameters or need other parameters as well.  It could also work with POSTs as well as GETs.

```
/things/1  -- HTML for "thing 1"
/things/1?format=json -- JSON for "thing 1"
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the convention of

```
/things/list -- HTML
/things/_listpage -- AJAX
```

The rule is that all AJAXed actions/views have a leading underscore. This tells me that they are never called top-level, and usually have no master page associated. In this case, I keep the action under the same controller in order to share any associated logic.

Typically in the list view I would have a

```
<% RenderAction("_listpage", "things", new {page = ViewData["CURRENT_PAGE"]}); %>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend a slight variation/elaboration to the suggestion by @RedFilter

```
/things/list -- HTML
/things/_list -- return HTML help and examples (more for you than them).
/things/_list/schema -- schema info
/things/_list/json -- JSON format
/things/_list/xml -- XML format
/things/_list/csv -- csv format
/things/_list/tab -- tab deliminated format
/things/_list/wdsl -- implemented soap web service
```

etc.. I feel it is more extensible. It looks scary, but it is easy to pass the data contents through a decorator based on the format requested making a whole host of file formats available with practically just a few lines of code.

Here is a crude conceptual example:

```
public ActionResult _list(string id)
{
    string data = "";
    DataTable oDataTable = this.oDAO.Get("list"); // pretend data retrieval

    try{
        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(id)){
            data = this.oDecorator.FormatData(id,oDataTable);
            this.ContentTypeChange(id); // change application handler
        }else{
            data = this.GetHelp("_list");
        }           
    }catch{}
    ViewData["data"] = data;
    return View();
}
```

...help can be more of a feature list, technical examples, or whatever you want. Of course you can start with just having native JSON and add more data formats to your decorator as requirements grow which is nice. For many of my projects it starts as a pure json rest pull by an AJAX and tends to bloom into other formats that are needed based on site popularity, so I have found this robust enough to use in an enterprise setting for smaller projects that often grow big.