# ASP.NET MVC controllers best practice for method naming

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I know next to nothing about MVC so my question might look a bit basic but here it is anyway : is it a good practice to have the same name for the method returning the view and the one saving the data ?

I see a lot of [examples like this one](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-controller-cs) where the overloaded "Create" does both jobs. Here's a snippet:

> ```
>     //
>     // GET: /Customer/Create> 
>     public ActionResult Create()
>     {
>         return View();
>     } 
>
>     //
>     // POST: /Customer/Create> 
>     [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
>     public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             // TODO: Add insert logic here> 
>             return RedirectToAction("Index");
>         }
>         catch
>         {
>             return View();
>         }
>     }
> ```

I personnaly find it confusing when overloads do completely different things depending on which I decide to choose. So what do you think ? Is it really the "best practice" to roll that way?

Comment: One is a GET and the other is a POST! (and never use `FormCollection` in MVC)

Comment: Yes , its not only about overloads , its the DataAnnotations which also tells you what kind of action you are performing , like [HttpGet]  and [HttpPost]

Comment: It's best to view controllers/actions as their own things, and not just classes/methods. While I would probably agree with you about having an overload do something different in a run-of-the-mill class, this pattern is actually very much recommended in the case of a controller action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the GET and the POST in this case usually share the same name, because they relate to the same user action.

See [Action Naming Convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118474/action-naming-convention?lq=1) for more guidance on Action naming.

Answer (score 1):

`I personally find it confusing when overloads do completely different things depending on which I decide to choose.`

Do they really? They are both concerning the same entity (a `Customer`). What you can do is name methods whatever you want and then add the `[ActionName]` attribute and that will be the name of the action. But yes. it's an MVC convention to name them the same way and then pick one or the other depending on whether you're using GET or POST.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if it is the POST method for that view then you should stick to the same name. The only time you should not follow this convention would be if you have multiple different POST methods for the same view for some reason or if you have a POST method which is used by multiple different views.

To provide a standard example:

You have a Create view which is used to create users. There is a HTTPGET Create() action and a HTTPPOST Create() action for posting the user details to the server. In this case you should use the same name.

You have a Dashboard view which displays some data from the database. You have some javascript which uses ajax to retrieve data from the server. In this case you may consider using a different name. E.g. GetData()